Movie similar to the Collector about a masked guy who sets up traps in his house
I saw this movie about eight years ago. 
It has a masked guy who sets up traps in his house that was isolated away from town or civilization. It was a two story house, with the main floor, upstairs and a basement. I don't remember the beginning (I think some teens walked into the home because they were lost?), but it was a group of teens who got trapped in the house with traps everywhere, behind every door and in every room. They had to be careful not to make them go off so they could escape. For one of the traps, there was a wire close to the floor and when the guy triggered it, a giant chandelier (I think it had spikes on it -- I don't remember) fell on him. Certain parts of the house had bear traps. 
The masked man was also in the house, so they had to be quiet to avoid him. I remember towards the end there was a girl and a guy who managed to get out of the house, and the masked guy started to chase them in a creepy white van. (side note: there was this one tree by the house that was located by the white van -- don't know if that helps) 

You sure it is not The Collector (2009)? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0844479/
The details seem to fit that movie. Even the white van is in there near the end of the movie. Here you can watch the movie, at 1:24:25 you can see the white van:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoxZdMziv8c

The Collector (2009)
There is a masked killer, teens in a booby trapped house, wire trap, bear trap and chandelier in the movie. You said you saw it about 8 years ago, this was made seven years ago, in 2009.
Here is a very detailed plot description.
It was a two story house: 

"we see another two-story house having some construction"

in his house that was isolated away from town or civilization:

"we see that the house in the middle of nowhere"

a wire close to the floor and when the guy triggered it, a giant chandelier fell on him (it had spikes on it):

"Arkin releases the wire for the chandelier, causing it to crush
  and stab the Collector."

Certain parts of the house had bear traps:

"dining room is filled with bear traps"

towards the end... the masked guy started to chase them in a creepy white van:
White van, towards the end of the movie:
 
Full movie here:



There is a sequel to this movie, The Collection (2012).

The title of the question specifically says that it's similar to this film...

Yeah, I know, but every detail seems to fit the movie.
